# PHP: extract URL's from a Flash SWF?

Tags: php, curl, flash, web-scraping

From an online brochure in Flash/SWF format, I need to extract all the URLs that point to different pages on a webshop.

With Firebug I can see that the SWF loads lots of different files, like images, javascript files even an XML file that seems to contain all the URLs.

So, using PHP, how would I extract/download these files that are loaded ?
cURL only gets the source of the HTML-page that loads the SWF, but not the SWF itself, let alone the files that the SWF loads.

Is there any way to download all files that the page with the SWF on it loads?

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting is not possible with pure php. As php does not "run" the flash content. Just like search engines can not properly index AJAX powered sites as the Javascript isnt "run".

You could possibly make a browser plugin (for like firefox) that captures and returns the request traffic ( or find a way for your plugin to interact with firebug to get it ), and have php call the browser up on the server (if the server has a gui) whenever it needs to do the fetching. This is obviously complicated to do, and having a server run a gui is resource intensive and introduces its own problems (security, etc ) as such i would rethink what you are trying to do.